# Finding why there is a difference in size for a CSV file with the same content

Tags: powershell, csv

**Situation**:

I run a macro to format an excel file, and save the formatted excel file as a .xlsx, the file size is 37 KB. I copy the content and save it into a new file, 30 KB.

**Issue**:

I want to know what the underlying differences are, so I tried using Spreadsheet compare. No differences. So I converted the files into CSVs and when I run this in powershell:

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Original_File.csv"
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New_File.csv"
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property MPFriendlyName -IncludeEqual
```

It tells me that there are not differences in content. Is there a command or any other tool that can explain to me what the underlying differences are? As in what exactly is the 7 KB?

**Side Note**:

This may sound stupid too, but I opened up the .xlsx Visual Basics thinking the difference in size is the saved macro, but it is not, there is no saved macro.

Comment: @root It is not

Comment: Could be quotation marks around all the fields in the larger copy, importing the CSV would remove them and only show field *contents*, not the "escape characters" and other csv specific formatting.

Comment: Compare the files visually using Notepad or similar to verify.

Comment: What meta does the larger file have set?  Word isn't going to compare that information.

Comment: try comparing with Notepad++ (there is a compare plugin available under `Plugins - Plugin manager`) and be sure to turn on `View - Show Symbols - Show all characters`. this will display all characters in the document, including whitespace and line delimiters, which take up bytes but aren't strictly "content".

Comment: Remember that `.xlsx` files (and `.docx` and `.pptx` files) are in zip format.  If you make a copy of each file (or just rename them) with an extension of ``.zip``, you’ll be able to open them, see their component pieces, and compare their sizes.  If only one or two components are different in size, look at them.  Even if you can’t make sense of the contents, their names might give you a clue.

Comment: @Simon I hadn't read your "Side Note" prior to my comment.

Comment: @Simon you can compare these files based on raw/plain text by replacing `import-csv` with `get-content` command. Or you can you can use bunch of other tools e.g.`fc` tool from cmd

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the help. I tried @FrankThomas method, but it tells me there are still no differences - as far as I can tell.

Comment: Excel does not shrink the size of the `xlsx` workbook file on  `Save`. Using `SaveAs` instead of `Save` causes Excel to create a brand new file for your workbook, and in the process, free up some space (e.g. _deleted macros_).  On the other side, `csv`s generated from both are the same as a `csv` contains merely current data.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that content-wise, they are identical. So your CSV comparison might be reliable. In order to figure out what could be different between the Excel files, you could do the following:

- Extract each Excel file to a separate directory (xlsx files are compressed archives containing XML files)
- Use a tool like WinMerge to compare the directories. This will highlight the exact XML files, and lines that are different.

Answer (score 0):

### Anatomy of A Spreadsheet

Using an existing 11KB spreadsheet, I copied the data out into a new spreadsheet, saved it and the file size was 10KB.

I opened both XLSX files into NotePad++, ran a compare, and there were immediate differences. These files looked like machine code though with very little readable text. I copied the text from one file into the other and saved. When I attempted to open in Excel again, the file came back as corrupted and would not open.

One of the few readable lines of code was this string:

```
worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels
```

Plugging that into a search led me to this article that explains everything:
[Anatomy of a Spreadsheet File](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php)

Once I realized a XLSX file is really a zip file I unpacked both files and compared the files and file structure. They were exactly the same with the exception of an additional "_rels" folder, inside the "worksheet" folder. This "_rels" folder contained an additional "sheet1.xml.rels" file that accounted for my 1KB difference.

I assumed the difference would be in the column widths or other minor formatting changes, but my 1KB XML file ended up as a schema file for a printer...